# nullpointerexception getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save some preferences within my android app. But when I am trying to get a sharedpreference I am getting a nullpointerexception. This is the error:

```
04-25 13:58:44.814: W/System.err(22795): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 13:58:44.824: W/System.err(22795):    at com.koeriers.standaard.SharedPreferences.setData(SharedPreferences.java:27)
04-25 13:58:44.829: W/System.err(22795):    at com.koeriers.standaard.actLogin.onCreate(actLogin.java:79)
04-25 13:58:44.834: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
04-25 13:58:44.839: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-25 13:58:44.844: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-25 13:58:44.849: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-25 13:58:44.854: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-25 13:58:44.859: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
04-25 13:58:44.864: W/System.err(22795):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 13:58:44.869: W/System.err(22795):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 13:58:44.874: W/System.err(22795):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-25 13:58:44.874: W/System.err(22795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 13:58:44.879: W/System.err(22795):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 13:58:44.884: W/System.err(22795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
04-25 13:58:44.889: W/System.err(22795):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-25 13:58:44.894: W/System.err(22795):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my SharedPreferences class:

```
package com.myapp.standaard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SharedPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

public static String GUID = "8BB4894B-92F7-45AF-9A40-B99D7A06A506";
public static String LicenseKey = "letmein";

EditText etLicense;
android.content.SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        etLicense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLicense);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Boolean setData(String setPreference, String setValue) {
    android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(setPreference, setValue);
    editor.commit();
    return true;
}

public String getData(String getPreference, String errorMessage) {
    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(getPreference, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String returnData = sharedPrefs.getString(getPreference, errorMessage);
    return returnData;
}
}
```

and this is the place in my Activity where I am trying to retrieve the value from my preference:

```
try{

        SharedPreferences sp = new SharedPreferences();
        licentie = sp.getData("LicenseKey", "Error loading license");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        licentie = "";
    }
```

Comment: In your code u didn't set any value for "LicenseKey" ,but you are trying to retreive it..

Comment: actLogin.java:79 check this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have'nt called the public Boolean

`setData(String setPreference, String setValue)`

anywhere that is why on `licentie = sp.getData("LicenseKey", "Error loading license");`

it is giving `nullpointerexception`.

First set the "LicenseKey" the try to retrieve it.

**Note -- The kind of Implementation you used according to me is not correct.**

Comment: I haven't called the boolean setData, because it should only retrieve the value of it the preference. So normally (if I understood the android developer reference correctly) it should display the "error loading license" message, since it is empty.

Comment: @user But there is not Variable present in the SharedPrefrences how can you use the get method. First of all set that variable then your get method will work.

Comment: yeah really stupid that I didn't noticed that, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: @user That is what first see your code. Anyways always happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
```

in this line sharedPrefs is not initialized. Better initialize your sharedPref in onCreate like following.

```
sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your sharedPrefs object before writing the data

```
sharedPrefs  = _activity.getSharedPreferences(SPName, android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Now set your data and then commit as

```
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```